# Issue in For-Each Loop with DataTable.Rows inside Web Service [vb.net]

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I have the following For Each loop inside of a web method that is part of a web service. It is meant to put all of the State names into one string so I can parse it out inside of an ajax control:

```
<WebMethod()> Public Function getState(ByVal country As String) As String
    Dim oresult As New DataTableResults
    Dim oData As New Location(_connstr)
    oresult = oData.getState(country)
    Dim states As String = ""
    For Each row As DataRow In oresult.dtData.Rows
        states = states & row.Item("StateText") & ","
    Next
    Return states
End Function
```

I tried stepping through it and it adds all of the items to the string, but an issue comes up when it exits the loop. It is then that it just shows that the webpage cannot be displayed and doesn't give any sort of error message other than 'HTTP 500 Internal Server Error.

Thanks

Comment: You have a comma at the end. Use `String.Join` instead: `states = String.Join(",", dresult.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(row) row("StateTex‌​t")))`

Comment: Thanks, why does having a comma at the end cause it to fail at the end of the loop?

Comment: i don't know if that causes your issue, otherwise i'd have posted it as answer.

Comment: Can you place breakpoint on `Return states`? and inspect `states`?

Comment: Ahh, okay. It's giving me an error for Function(row) - Lambda parameter 'row' hides a variable in an enclosing block, a previously defined range variable, or an implicitly declared variable in a query expression.

Comment: T.S. I tried putting a breakpoint at my return statement and it goes to the error page before it hits it. But inspecting prior to this shows the full list of states separated by commas

Comment: You need to post whole method then

Comment: Tim - Changing that gives me: System.ArgumentException: Column &#39;StateTex‌t&#39; does not belong to table dtData.

Comment: T.S - whole method is posted

Comment: What if you try to wrap this whole thing into `try-catch` before `return` Declare `states` outside of try-catch

Comment: T.S. - It returns the string correctly when it's inside of the Try-Catch. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the exception message you intercept in `catch(e as Exception)` ?

Comment: It doesn't show any exception message